# VBA that copies rows into new sheet based on each row's cell contents (example included)

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm hoping for some help to automate a process that will otherwise involve copying and editing some 10,000 rows.

This is stuff relating to location data. Essentially, there are tons of these Master Rows but they do not have individual rows for Unit Numbers. I am hoping to get something to expand these into individual Unit Number rows based on what is in Column N. Column N is intended to follow a strict format of being a comma-seperated single cell list for each row.

Below is an example from **Sheet 1** of what each row will have and needs to be expanded upon. Note that **Column N** is green and follows a consistent formatting and this will be the determinant for how many times these rows will each be expanded upon.

[image: Master Rows with User-Input Data in Col N]

Below is **Sheet 2** and what I want the VBA to create from **Sheet 1**. You can see that each row has been expanded based on the contents of **Column N** from **Sheet 1**. 
[image: Intended Result]

Like I said, it is expected that this will involve some several thousand rows to create.

Comment: Are you asking someone to write the code for you or just guide you in general with what you will need to write

Comment: Best bet is to record a macro that does want you want it to do. Then try to edit it and make it flexible for general purposes - otherwise come back here posting the code and suggesting what you're trying to accomplish that the macro can't do.

Comment: To be honest, I feel it's a bit beyond my comprehension of VBA coding and it's part of a project that I'm only going to be a part of for the next 3 days. I'm trying to make things easier for the team before I leave.

Comment: I realise also now that what I am wanting done can be achieved by Selecting a Cell, converting it from "Text to Columns" then copy and Special Pasting that Transposed. But that is still a little too manual for vast quantities of data to be processed considering it only pastes the unit numbers and not the rest of the data for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

    Dim sht1, sht2, rwSrc As Range, rwDest As Range, v, arr, n

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    sht2.Range("A2:M2").Resize(3, 13).Value = sht1.Range("A2:M2").Value

    Set rwDest = sht2.Range("A2:M2")   'destination start row
    Set rwSrc = sht1.Range("A2:M2")    'source row

    Do While Application.CountA(rwSrc) > 0

        v = rwSrc.EntireRow.Cells(1, "N").Value 'list of values

        If InStr(v, ",") > 0 Then
            'list of values: split and count
            arr = Split(v, ",")
            n = UBound(arr) + 1
        Else
            'one or no value
            arr = Array(v)
            n = 1
        End If

        'duplicate source row as required
        rwDest.Resize(n, 13).Value = rwSrc.Value

        'copy over the unit values
        rwDest.Cells(1, "G").Resize(n, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)

        'offset to next destination row
        Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(n, 0)

        'next source row
        Set rwSrc = rwSrc.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested it and works perfectly for the data I have. You've literally saved me and my colleagues 100s of hours.

Answer (score 0):

This does the work in same sheet...  Pls copy the value to "Sheet2" before executing this.  Not sure about efficiency though.

```
    Public Sub Test()


    Dim lr As Long          ' To store the last row of the data range
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim Str As String       ' To store the string in column N


    lr = Range("N65536").End(xlUp).Row   'Getting the last row of the data

    For i = lr To 2 Step -1
        Str = Range("N" & i).Value      ' Getting the value from Column N
        counter = 1
        For Each s In Split(Str, ",")
            If counter > 1 Then
                Range("A" & (i + counter - 1)).EntireRow.Insert     ' Inserting rows for each value in column N
                Range("G" & (i + counter - 1)).Formula = s          ' Updating the value in Column G
            Else
                Range("G" & i).Formula = s                          ' No need to insert a new row for first value
            End If
            counter = counter + 1

        Next s
    Next i


    lr = Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row

    '  Pulling down other values from the first value row other rows
    Range("A1:N" & lr).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

    '  Pasting the data as Values to avoid future formula issues.
    Range("A1:N" & lr).Copy
    Range("A1:N" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    MsgBox "Done"




    End Sub
```